# How can i train a Image classifier model with tensorflow in Python and use the trained model in Java application?

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a client-Server Application where client is an android device and server is a windows Pc.it would be easy to do socket programming in java for building the complete application.At first, I tried to build the server side completely in python because of the image classifier I wrote in python. but it got me into problems when I started working on the socket.Now, I want to use python trained model in java.

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`python trained model` server serve http api ,accept the image , return classification result

Answer (score 0):

You can save the trained model in h5 file format which can be used in both java and python code piece.

You can use [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-deep-learning-models-with-java-62d80464f34a) for reference